# How to use Piwik's Javascript's tracking client along with angulartics?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, matomo, angulartics

Since I'm tracking an angularjs single page mobile app (and new to tracking implementation), I included the angulartics module to perform views/virtualpages tracking. My analytics provider is Piwik. I was wondering if, despite the fact that I implemented the angulartics.piwik module, will the other piwik javascript client methods still work?:

tracking goals (`_paq.push(['trackGoal', 1]);`)

custom variables(`_paq.push(['setCustomVariable', , ,]);`)

and all of the other methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angulartics does not interfere with the vendor library; you can still use it directly if you want.